# How to deal with reference not found when trying to Add-Type in PowerShell, when the same dll loads fine in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, informix

I am trying to reference the IBM.Data.DB2 and IBM.Data.Informix libraries from PowerShell.

I have some Visual Studio test code in which I simply added references to those dlls and started coding, everything went fine.

When attempting to add the same references in PowerShell I try the following:

```
try{
$DataType4 = Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40\IBM.Data.DB2.dll"
}
catch
{
$_.Exception | Format-List * -force
}
```

When trying to run this I get an extended error list which complains that Microsoft.ReportingServices isn't found (I think it isn't installed on this machine anyway; I've printed out my GAC and it doesn't appear there, though there are many references to `Microsoft.ReportViewer`; the successful Visual Studio project doesn't include `Microsoft.ReportingServices` in its references). From the look of things, LoaderException contains this information multiple times so I've only included one copy:

```
Types        : {IBM.Data.DB2.CS_FitHighPrecisionType, IBM.Data.DB2.LLIST, IBM.Data.DB2.LISTLOCK, IBM.Data.DB2.ADP...}
LoaderExceptions : {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
               File name: 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

               WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
               To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
               Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
StackTrace   :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
                  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
                  at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand.LoadAssemblyFromPathOrName(List`1 generatedTypes)
                  at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand.EndProcessing()
                  at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
```

Can anyone explain why this seems to run fine in Visual Studio, but not in PowerShell? Am I retrieving the exception correctly? Is there some way around the missing Microsoft component, seeing as Visual Studio copes fine without it?

I feel like I'm doing something obviously wrong and heading off tilting at windmills, but I can't seem to find any other mentions of this issue.

**EDIT:** This is a screenshot of my tiny test project along with its references. It just fetches a table of data and dumps it into a DataGridView, but it shows the minimal amount of coding required to hook up a connection using these drivers.
[image]

Comment: Where is the target dll? Some parts of the assembly load path are application relative (and dependent on the applications config). Different applications will have different search paths.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The IBM dlls are in the directory specified in the code (each fails with similar errors), and the MS dll doesn't appear to be installed on my machine, and isn't referenced in the successful VS project. I'll edit the post to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a weekend reboot, I've revised my answer:

It turns out that the exceptions thrown during the load process are non-fatal, so catching them and ignoring them works well enough for test code.
If the `Add-Type` fails in a more serious manner, I've got another try-catch around the entire execution block, and actually trying to access an Informix object on a "real" load failure throws an exception that's caught there.

Test code included for the benefit of any future searchers:

```
try{
$DataType7 = Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40\IBM.Data.Informix.dll"
}
catch
{
    #Throw a horrendous mass of exceptions, which we ignore, but output.
    $_.Exception | Format-List * -force
}


$ifxCStr = New-Object -TypeName IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnectionStringBuilder
$ifxCStr.Server = "x"
$ifxCStr.Database = "x"
$ifxCStr.UserID = "x"
$ifxCStr.Password = "x"

$ifxConn = New-Object -TypeName IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection($ifxCStr.ConnectionString)
$ifxConn.Open()


$ifxCommand = $ifxConn.CreateCommand()
$ifxCommand.CommandText = "SELECT FIRST 100 * FROM tbl_x"

$ifxReader = $ifxCommand.ExecuteReader()

$ifxTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$ifxTable.Load($ifxReader)
$ifxTable | Out-GridView

$ifxConn.Close()
```